# R: vennerable Venn: wrong positioning for area numbers

Tags: r

I want to make a 3 entry weighted Venn diagram.
To do so I am using the "vennerable" package as it seems to be the most suited for that.

However when I'm plotting my data the "weight" of the the different areas look ok but the position of the values are not at the right place

Here is my script:

```
library(Vennerable)
library(VennDiagram)

data1 <- read.csv("1_1accessoutput.csv", header = FALSE)
data2 <- read.csv("2_1accessoutput.csv", header = FALSE)
data3 <- read.csv("3_1accessoutput.csv", header = FALSE)

vectorA <- as.vector(data1$V1)
vectorB <- as.vector(data2$V1)
vectorC <- as.vector(data3$V1)

Vmetadata <- list(test1 = vectorA, test2 = vectorB, test3 = vectorC)     
Vmeta <- Venn(Vmetadata)
Vmeta3 <- Vmeta[, c("test1", "test2", "test3")]
C3 <- compute.Venn(Vmeta3, doWeights = TRUE)
plot(C3)
```

My data are too big to put them here so i also tried with manual values entry
And i got the exact same issue (values out of the corresponding areas)

here the code:

```
Vcombo <- Venn(SetNames = c("test1", "test2", "test3"), Weight = c(0, 50, 54, 7, 46, 29, 91, 207))
plot(Vcombo)
```

I have tried to play around with the SetLabels and the gpList options without success.
Is it something to do with values incompatible with Weighted Venn drawing?

Is someone know what might be the reason of this problem and if you have an idea to fix it?
i just want to make a script able to make weighted area for the values above.

Comment: Please post a small, reproducible dataset which generates this problem

Comment: You might also mention that `Vennerable` is from R-forge, while it has dependencies at `Bioconductor`

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I have installed Vennerable Via
install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
It also need biocLite("RBGL") via source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

For the example dataset you can use the values in the second code i have posted (Weight = c(0, 50, 54, 7, 46, 29, 91, 207)). These values come from my data and give the exact same problem ie: (the value between test2 and test3 and the value for text 2 in the bottom of the venn are completely out of their area (moved to the top area))

Comment: I will also try to upload my data sets and make a link to download

Comment: Here are the 3 CSV files that you can use with the first script:
http://www.filedropper.com/11accessoutput_1
http://www.filedropper.com/21accessoutput_1
http://www.filedropper.com/31accessoutput_1